# Negated would vs could vs did - which to use?

Tags: word-choice, negation

I am watching a movie with my friend and we see a scene in which a person drops a catch. Now if I wan to ask about that person, would it be okay to ask in this way?

> Who is that guy who wouldn't/didn't/couldn't catch that ball?

And can we use *wouldn't*, *couldn't* and *didn't* interchangeably here?

Answer (score 1):

### didn't (opposite of "did")

This is the most neutral of the three options.  It suggests that the player might have caught the ball, but on this occasion did not.

### couldn't (opposite of "could")

This implies a failure - the player had an opportunity to catch the ball, but was not able to do so.

### wouldn't (opposite of "would")

This implies a refusal.  The player had an opportunity to catch the ball, but chose not to.

Answer (score 0):

The differences between the 3 are the following:

> Who is that guy who wouldn't catch that ball?

Who is that guy who could catch the ball but didn't want to catch it?

> Who is that guy who couldn't catch that ball?

Who is that guy who tried to catch it, but failed to catch it?

> Who is that guy who didn't catch that ball?

Who is that guy who wanted to catch the ball, but didn't catch it?

Comment: *Didn't* does not imply that the guy *wanted* to catch the ball; it doesn't say anything at all about the player's state of mind or the reason the ball was not caught.